# Get HTTP request logs from kubernetes pods ? (Running JupyterHub)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, amazon-eks

I am running JupyterHub application on a kubernetes cluster (specifically, managed kubernetes on aws, EKS). Each JupyterHub user has their own pod, when they spin up their JupyterHub notebook server.

I need to be able to monitor the HTTP requests that are being made from their notebook server.

**Is there any way for me to enable this type of logging? And if so, how could I consume these logs?**

Answer (score 0):

With [Istio](https://istio.io/) service mesh you will be able to trace all incoming/outgoing HTTP requests within your JupyterHub pod.

Alternatively, you may use [Zipkin](https://zipkin.io/) - a distributed tracing system